# Bash history deduplication causing dangerous multi-shell behaviour

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, history

I am using the following code in my .bash_profile to filter and de-duplicate my bash history:

```
shopt -s histappend
HISTSIZE=100000
HISTFILESIZE=100000
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a;history -c;history -r;$PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

It works wonderfully, however the following side effect is produced:

Let's say I have two terminals/tabs open:

- 1st tab: folder: `~`, last command run: `wget big_file...` (or anything lengthy)
- 2nd tab: folder: some random temp folder, last command run: `rm -rf *`

Now if I go from the 2nd to the 1st tab, and press the UP key, it re-runs the last command, like everything is OK.

Now comes the dangerous bit: if I press UP again, it'll insert `rm -rf *` and if I don't notice it the very moment I've just deleted all my data.

Can you recommend me a .bash_profile setting for history which does de-duplication/filtering but doesn't allow such things to happen?

Comment: Remove the PROMPT_COMMAND.

Comment: But then would it still make sure that lines are deduplicated and the newest ones are kept at the bottom?

Comment: Lines will be consistent in each terminal separately.

Comment: I believe having the -a there is useful for saving shell regularly, but -c and -r is the one causing the intermixing. My only question is whether I should use -a, -n or -w.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HISTIGNORE` to ignore the ones you may consider dangerous.

```
HISTIGNORE='rm -rf *:dangercmd -c 2:echo and so on'
```